# Finding element of file in KSH

Tags: sed, ksh, string, xml

please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

I have this file called "res.xml"

```xml
<sequence type="a">
  <transaction>
   <branchSerial>1</branchSerial>
   <postingDate>2021-08-02</postingDate>
   <postingTime>2021-08-06 19:42:49 UTC</postingTime>
   <step type="a">
    <record type="c" label="deviceRecord">
     <operation option="V">View</operation>
     <tableName>DEVICE</tableName>
     <tableDescription>Device</tableDescription>
     <rowDescription>person@chello.com</rowDescription>
    </record>
   </step>
  </transaction>
 </sequence>
```

I am trying to pull the postingDate and put  into a variable. My script:

```bsh
#!/bin/ksh


dbDATE=$(sed -n -e "s/<postingDate>\([0-9]*\)<\/postingDate>/\1/p" res.xml)

  echo "current DB date: $dbDATE"
```

when I run it, I get nothing, just blank.

It is very odd because I have used the same logic elsewhere without problems. Can anybody see what I am missing???

Thank you so much for any help you can provide

Comment: Your date string contains hyphens as well as digits: `[0-9-]*`

Comment: ... although you should probably be using an XML aware tool such as `xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//postingDate' dateRes.xml`

Comment: @steeldriver thank you so much! I added the '-' and its working proper, you're a life saver.. I would love to use one of the sweet XML tools out there but this on my company's server where we wont be able to download anything external. Thanks again, cheers!

Comment: @ShelbyAnne You need to have a word with your managers about what tools you have to work with. If you were working in _any other area_ and you were not given the correct tools to work with, you would be absolutely correct in  calling your managers negligent.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

works fine with below command

```
dbdate=$(awk -F "[<>]" '/postingDate/{print $3}' res.xml)

echo -e "current DB date: $dbdate"
current DB date: 2021-08-02
```

Comment: Please  let me know the reason for downvote

Comment: This worked very well for me thank you! I don't know why someone downvoted. Can you please explain why {print $3} part worked?

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with your `sed` approach is that you do not allow the date to contain dashes.

---

To extract the data from the file that you show, you would use an XML-aware parser for the command line.

One example of such a parser is `xmlstarlet`, which you would use either like this:

```bsh
dbDATE=$( xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/sequence/transaction/postingDate' res.xml )
```

or, if the node you're looking for the value of is the only such node,

```bsh
dbDATE=$( xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//postingDate' res.xml )
```

Another XML-aware parser is [`xq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/), an XML parser wrapper around the JSON parser `jq`:

```bsh
dbDATE=$( xq -r '.sequence.transaction.postingDate' res.xml )
```

---

All of the above assumes that the `sequence` node contains only *a single* `transaction` node.  Do we want to support multiple transactions (the word "sequence" hints that this may contain a *list* of transactions), you will also need to decide whether you want to pick the *first* transaction or specific transaction given some other condition.

Assuming we want the transaction with  a `branchSerial` value of `1`.  With `xmlstarlet`:

```bsh
dbDATE=$( xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/sequence/transaction[branchSerial=1]/postingDate' res.xml )
```

With `xq`:

```bsh
dbDATE=$( xq -r '.sequence.transaction[] | select(.branchSerial == "1").postingDate' res.xml )
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you set the .xml output to a variable, you can do the following:

```
xmlData='
<sequence type="a">
  <transaction>
   <branchSerial>1</branchSerial>
   <postingDate>2021-08-02</postingDate>
   <postingTime>2021-08-06 19:42:49 UTC</postingTime>
   <step type="a">
    <record type="c" label="deviceRecord">
     <operation option="V">View</operation>
     <tableName>DEVICE</tableName>
     <tableDescription>Device</tableDescription>
     <rowDescription>person@chello.com</rowDescription>
    </record>
   </step>
  </transaction>
 </sequence>
'

date=$(echo "$xmlData" | grep "postingDate" | tr '>' " " | tr '<' " " | awk '{print $2}')
```

---

Since you said you are pulling it in from a file though, you can even do this:

```
date=$(cat res.xml | grep "postingDate" | tr '>' " " | tr '<' " " | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: This works for he data as given, but not if there are several transactions with `postingDate` entries, nor if the `postingDate` node has attributes.

Comment: I agree. I gave a specific use case since he gave a specific datafile rather than an example of one